# How to relayout RecyclerView after IME candidates is hidden?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make a chat-like screen with RecyclerView as [this](https://github.com/YusukeIwaki/RecyclerViewBug/blob/master/abstract.png)

However RecyclerView (LinearLayoutManager) doesn't works as I expected...
How can I fix or avoid this problem?

#### Detail:

The problem is also reproducible with very simplified Activity shown below.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="none"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initializeRecyclerView();
    }

    private void initializeRecyclerView() {
        RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        Adapter recyclerAdapter = new Adapter(createItemList());
        recycler.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);

    }

    private static ArrayList<String> createItemList(){
        ArrayList<String> items= new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
            items.add(String.format("item %02d",20-i));
        }
        return items;
    }

}
```

RecyclerView is **not completely relayout after IME candidates are hidden** shown in [this movie](https://github.com/YusukeIwaki/RecyclerViewBug/blob/master/test.gif).

This problem is fixed by adding "adjustResize" into MainActivity's windowSoftInputMode, but I don't want to use it. Solution *without changing windowSoftInputMode* is wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. What will help you is creating a custom adapter which has a different viewholder and onbindview for the IME candidates. Then you can easily hide the IME candidates by changing LayoutView.Params and setting height to zero. This is how I've done it, sounds like a workaround but works for me. Hope this helps.

Comment: I suggest to set visibility as GONE

Comment: That is exactly what I tried at first, however, in my case while the view goes away, the Recylerview leaves an empty space the size of the view (maybe I was doing something wrong) so setting height equal to zero worked better for me.